# Remover menu navigation controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Como removo esse menu em cinza da minha webview acho que é alguma coisa relacionada ao navigation controller n tenho certeza

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essa barra se refere a **NavigationBar** que é exibida por padrão na **NavigationController**.

Para ocultar essa barra, você pode simplesmente chamar o método *setNavigationBarHidden* da sua *NavigationController*.

```
self.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
```

Lembrando que o *self* se refere a instância da sua NavigationController.

[Documentação da Apple que fala sobre a NavigationController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller)